# How to use timestamp as seed

Tags: anchor, pda, seed

I'm trying to use the current timestamp as seed but i can't find the right way, i even try to passing as string and getting a deserialize error.

here is the code for my program:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("5hH748CgCFrbuJ19GtdgaB9M1pV5VuUuTicTyz8Jhr3d");


#[program]
pub mod bubbles {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_game(ctx: Context<CreateGame>, players: Vec<Pubkey>, timestamp: String, items_by_line: u8, lines: u8) -> Result<()> {
        
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(timestamp: String)]
pub struct CreateGame<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        space = 1000,
        seeds = [b"game".as_ref(), &payer.key().to_bytes(), timestamp.as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Game {
    pub board: Vec<Bubble>,
    pub players: Vec<Pubkey>,
    pub turn: u64,
    pub updated: u64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Bubble {
    pub player: u8,
    pub amount: u8,
}
```

Here my test:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Bubbles } from "../target/types/bubbles";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js"
import { PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js"

describe("bubbles", () => {
 // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
 anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

 const program = anchor.workspace.Bubbles as Program<Bubbles>;
 const payer = (program.provider as anchor.AnchorProvider).wallet;
 const player1 = new PublicKey("EjPpXXDykPawauyZHsBMtxGwG7K4iFmxdvB6ockM56ZN")
 const player2 = new PublicKey("CUtKCTar8gb5VYCDWbX5yFMVrhbnod9aCNf4cfhD2qPK")
 const timestamp = `${Date.now()}`

 it("Is initialized!", async () => {
   const [groupPublicKey] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
     [Buffer.from("game"), payer.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from(timestamp),],
     program.programId,
   )
   const tx = await program.methods.createGame(
     [player1, player2],
     timestamp,
     5,
     10,
   ).accounts({
     game: groupPublicKey,
     payer: payer.publicKey,
     systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
   })
   .rpc();
   console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
 });
});
```

and here the error i'm getting:

```
 Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.
      at Function.parse (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:135:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:276:35)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

any idea how can i approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing that pops out at me is to change:

```
#[instruction(timestamp: String)]
```

to:

```
#[instruction(players: Vec<Pubkey>, timestamp: String)]
```

Because you need the 1st-nth arguments from your instruction in the `instruction` macro, where n is the highest indexed argument you need from your instruction arguments. So since even if you only need your 2nd argument (`timestamp`), you have to pull in the 1st (`players`) as well.

Answer (score 2):

we had a similar challenge some times ago and we solved like the following:

```
use crate::{
    errors::VyperVaultsErrorCode,
    state::{EpochData, VaultConfig},
};
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use rust_decimal::Decimal;

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(input_data: InitializeEpochDataInputData)]
pub struct InitializeEpochDataContext<'info> {
    /// Vault Configuration
    #[account()]
    pub vault_config: Box<Account<'info, VaultConfig>>,

    /// Epoch Data parameters account initialized
    #[account(init, seeds = [vault_config.key().as_ref(), input_data.start_timestamp.to_be_bytes().as_ref(),  b"epoch_data".as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = EpochData::LEN)]
    pub epoch_data: Box<Account<'info, EpochData>>,

    /// Payer for the `epoch_data` account creation
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    // System program
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize, Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct InitializeEpochDataInputData {
    pub start_timestamp: i64,
}

pub fn handler(
    ctx: Context<InitializeEpochDataContext>,
    input_data: InitializeEpochDataInputData,
) -> Result<()> {
  
    // ...

    Ok(())
}
```

Using the `start_timestamp.to_be_bytes()` make the trick in the PDA seed.

Following for the tests (copying from our sdk, some methods are left behind, happy to share more if needed):

```
static async initializeIX(client: ProgramClient, vaultConfig: VaultConfig): Promise<anchor.web3.TransactionInstruction> {
    const epochData = await EpochData.findCurrentEpochPdaAddress(client, vaultConfig);

    return await client.program.methods
      .initializeEpochData({
        startTimestamp: new anchor.BN(await this.getCurrentEpochStartTimestamp(vaultConfig)),
      })
      .accounts({
        vaultConfig: vaultConfig.publicKey,
        epochData: epochData,
        signer: client.provider.wallet.publicKey,
      })
      .instruction();
  }
```